# Failed to bind properties under 'spring.ora-datasource' to javax.sql.DataSource:

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I'm getting failed when compilling app

```
spring.ora-datasource.username=root
spring.ora-datasource.password=root
spring.ora-datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.ora-datasource.maximumPoolSize=2
```

my oracle dependency

```
<!--Oracle-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.ora-datasource' to javax.sql.DataSource:

Property: spring.ora-datasource.driver-class-name
Value: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:11:41
Reason: Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try `spring.ora-datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`
Note the package name.